# pretty photo rel links?

Tags: php, iframe

I don't know if anybody's going to know about pretty photo, but it's a image gallery box that opens images in a window like facebook.

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

Basically a user will click on a persons profile and it will open a page in this pretty photo box. It is capable of loading images and pages but when i do this i get an error saying "image can not be loaded make sure the path is correct."

I'm trying it with google for now to see if i can get the page to open but it won't even work with google. Does anyone know where i'm going wrong and can anyone show me where to fix this?

```
<?
    echo
"<a href=\"http://www.google.co.uk\" rel=\"prettyPhoto[1] \"><img width=90px height= 90px src=\"data/photos/{$chat['id']}/_default.jpg\"/></a>"; ?>
```

Comment: What is the html output?

Comment: Did you try `rel="prettyPhoto"`

Answer (score 1):

've tried putting the image path in the hyperlink?

```
<?php
    echo "<a href=\"data/photos/{$chat['id']}/_default.jpg\" rel=\"prettyPhoto[1] \"><img width=90px height= 90px src=\"data/photos/{$chat['id']}/_default.jpg\"/></a>"; 
?>
```